# Media query and max width 1000px not activating until screen width is approx. 980px?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

All the divs I used for my web page layout are specified with their own widths and heights, the heights are all different but their widths are all the same: 1000px. My media query

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 #container {
  width: 100%;
 }
 #desktop_ul {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .desktop_li {
  margin: 0 0.5%;
 }
 #article {
  width: 100%;
 }
 #footer {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

is supposed to make all these divs transform into percents when the browser window is shrunk down to 1000px or less, but when I slowly shrink down the window, I get a horizontal scroll bar for a brief second, or for about 20px and then it disappears once I reach about 980px.

Why doesn't the media query activate at 1000px, why do I have to shrink down my window to 980px for it to activate?

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar is about 20px, I guess I should have factored that in.

Comment: show us a fiddle or the rest of your code, so we can help you better